# Convert factor into numeric values (R)

Tags: r

I´m sure this is simple, but I couldn´t find the right answer to my specific problem.

I have a data frame in R. The first column has a DateTime (POSIXct) format.
The values in all the other columns have the format "factor".
Since all of the values in these columns are numbers I want to **convert them in to a numeric format**.
An additional problem is that since I´m from europe the numbers (factors) have **"," as a decimal mark**.

How do I convert these columns in to a numeric format?

Comment: Why couldn't you find the answer? "factor to numeric R", "comma decimal to numeric R"? You already have all the correct terminology in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the links! But since I´m very new to R I´m having problems applying the function to the data frame columns (2 to the last column). The result should still be a data frame. Do you have any hints?